# Blending two images with PIL: Different sizes and different alpha transparency per row

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have two images (JPGs). Both are the same width but image2 is shorter than image1. I want to paste image2 on top of image1 (top aligned) and for each row in image2 I want to blend into image1 with a different alpha transparency value (to make it smoothly blend from bottom to top ).

I'm using Python PIL and because I'm new to it can't figure out the best way to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a mask which is the same size as the image2, mode `'L'`. Fill it with gray values from 0 to 255, representing the alpha transparency you want. Use `paste` to put image2 into image1, using the gray image as the mask parameter.